# Is this patent issued?

Tags: international, wipo

In reference to the patent: [WO2005071644A1](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2005071644A1)

How can I find out whether any patents have been granted resultant from this WIPO application?

Answer (score 1):

so far, there does not seem to be a granted patent on this application.  The application has entered the National phase in India.  Please see the details here:
https://patentscope.wipo.int/search/en/detail.jsf?docId=WO2005071644&recNum=1&tab=NationalPhase&maxRec=&office=&prevFilter=&sortOption=&queryString=

The National Number is :3252/CHENP/2007, and it was  Published: 16.11.2007

Answer (score 0):

Status: The application is deemed to be withdrawn.

https://patentscope.wipo.int/search/en/search.jsf

Search in this database.

Comment: This could be an acceptable answer if you were to add more detail. I followed the link and it didn't go to the specific application. Also, it isn't at all clear where you get the information about it being withdrawn. Perhaps a bit more detail with a screenshot or two would be helpful.